# Printing job not triggered

Tags: c#, .net, printing

Below code we have implemented for printing a document, but print job is not triggering(print is not coming).We are not getting any exceptions as well

```
// Code for priniting document directly to the printer//

Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
clientSocket.NoDelay = true;
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(hostAddress);
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(ip, Convert.ToInt32(PortNumber));
clientSocket.Connect(ipep);
clientSocket.Send(fileBytes);
clientSocket.Close(); 
MessageBox.Show("Printed Successfully");'
```

Comment: which language do you write code in? add it in your question tags

Comment: formatting improvment
add related tag

Comment: What port number are you sending it to? The most common printing port would be 9100. Also, what kind of file are you sending to the printer? Does the printer support the file type being sent?